# How to consume and parse different Avro messages in kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-schema-registry

In My application Kafka topics are dedicated to a domain(can't change that) and multiple different types of events (1 Event = 1 Avro schema message) related to that domain being produced by different micro-services in that one topic.
Now I have only one consumer app in which I should be able to apply different schema dynamically (by inspecting event name in message) and transform in appropriate pojo object(generated by specific Avro schema) for further event specific actions.
Whatever example I find on net is all about single schema type message consumer so need some help.

Answer (score 3):

Related blog post: https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/

How to configure the consumer:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html#avro-deserializer

https://github.com/openweb-nl/kafka-graphql-examples/blob/307bbad6f10e4aaa6b797a3bbe3b6620d3635263/graphql-endpoint/src/main/java/nl/openweb/graphql_endpoint/service/AccountCreationService.java#L47

https://github.com/openweb-nl/kafka-graphql-examples/blob/307bbad6f10e4aaa6b797a3bbe3b6620d3635263/graphql-endpoint/src/main/resources/application.yml#L20

You need the generated Avro classes on the classpath. Most likely by adding a dependency.